# Can't connect to zookeeper and then hbase master shuts down

Tags: java, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I use hbase 0.94.1 and zookeeper 3.3.6 after few attempts, the master of hbase shuts down and the sw exits

Those are the errors that I get from the shell

```
12/09/26 18:58:35 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=hconnection
12/09/26 18:58:35 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server /127.0.0.1:2181
12/09/26 18:58:35 INFO zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: The identifier of this process is 5133@xxx-xxx
12/09/26 18:58:35 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
12/09/26 18:58:35 WARN zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocket: Connected to an old server; r-o mode will be unavailable
12/09/26 18:58:35 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x13a037edbb2000c, negotiated timeout = 40000
12/09/26 18:58:36 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
12/09/26 18:58:36 INFO client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Closed zookeeper sessionid=0x13a037edbb2000c
12/09/26 18:58:36 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x13a037edbb2000c closed
12/09/26 18:58:36 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down

org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: Retried 10 times
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.<init>(HBaseAdmin.java:127)
    at util.HBaseHelper.<init>(HBaseHelper.java:29)
    at util.HBaseHelper.getHelper(HBaseHelper.java:33)
    at driver.ABoxHbaseTableMaker.makeTable(ABoxHbaseTableMaker.java:39)
    at driver.ABoxImporterDriver.run(ABoxImporterDriver.java:55)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:79)
    at driver.ABoxImporterDriver.main(ABoxImporterDriver.java:32)
    at gui.Main.jButton1ActionPerformed(Main.java:274)
    at gui.Main.access$3(Main.java:241)
    at gui.Main$5.actionPerformed(Main.java:160)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    ...
```

T tried to change the port but nothing.

Those are the config files:

**zoo.cfg:**

```
tickTime=2000
dataDir=/home/.../.../zookeeper-3.3.6/data
clientPort=2181
```

**hbase-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>file:///home/.../.../hbase-0.94.1/hbDATA/</value>
  </property>
 <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>localhost</value>
 </property>
 <property>
    <name>zookeeper.znode.parent</name>
    <value>file:///home/.../.../hbase-0.94.1/hbDATA/</value>
 </property>
 <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
    <value>2181</value>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't have only one zookeeper host (localhost). At least three zookeeper hosts should be configured in the property ``hbase.zookeeper.quorum`` in hbase-site.xml

Comment: even if i'm trying the code on my local machine ? (is not necessary an hdfs for this tries)

Comment: Oh ok, that's fine. But then I wonder why you gave a value for `zookeeper.znode.parent`. That's not something you should normally configure just to try the code. Check the description here http://hbase.apache.org/book/config.files.html that is, remove this property from your xml and try to run again.

Comment: i removed from hbase-site.xml the `zookeeper.znode.parent` (and remained localhost on the qorum property) but it gave me the same error

Comment: ok solved , i ran ./hbase-config.sh and ./zookeepers.sh and that solved the problem ... thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using HBase in standalone mode, you don't even need all these properties..Although, a pseudo or a fully distributed mode required additional settings..By looking at your config props, I am assuming you are using HBase in local mode.So you can skip all those things. And for a pseudo distributed mode HBase's default ZK is sufficient.